# Python: how to distinguish between socket error and timeout?

Tags: python, sockets, exception

I'm having the following code:

```
try:
    while 1:
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(5);
        s.connect((HOST,PORT))
        print("before send")
        #time.sleep(10);
        #s.sendall('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nHost: www.google.lt\r\n\r\n')
        data=s.recv(52)
        print("after send");
        s.close()
        if string.find(data,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK") == -1:
            print("Lost Connection")
        print(data)
        time.sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("CTRL C occured")
except socket.error:
    print("socket error occured: ")
except socket.timeout:
    print("timeout error")
```

I have commented the sendall function to test how recv generates timeout exception.
But the problem is that i get socket.error exception.
If i change the last lines of code to:

```
except socket.timeout:
    print("timeout error")
except socket.error:
     print("socket error occured: ")
```

Then i get socket.timeout exception.
So what exception is really generated?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`socket.timeout` is a subclass of `socket.error`. Really it's `socket.timeout`. When you catch   a `socket.error` first, you catch a more general case.

```
>>> issubclass(socket.timeout, socket.error)
True
```

This code is correct:

```
except socket.timeout:
 print("timeout error")
except socket.error:
 print("socket error occured: ")
```

Try to catch specifically `socket.timeout`, then other `socket.error`s.

Comment: Using the above I get type object '_socketobject' has no attribute named 'timeout'